# Template allows lvalue to become bound with rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

This program:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Dog 
{ 
    int legs; 
} adog;

Dog gimmeadog() { return adog; }

void walk(Dog && d) { cout << "Nonconst right dog walk\n"; }

//template<class T> void walk(T && d) { d.legs=3; cout << "Nonconst right something walk\n"; }

int main() {
    Dog mydog = gimmeadog();
    walk(mydog);    
    return 0;
}
```

correctly fails to compile on gcc because:

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘Dog&&’ to lvalue of type ‘Dog’
  walk(mydog);
```

but if you un-comment the template it happily binds and prints "Nonconst right something walk".

Why? What type is `T` taking when it works? Is this not defeating the object of rvalue references?

Comment: If you cause a compilation error in the template instantiation, most compilers will tell you which type they instantiated it with. For example: https://godbolt.org/z/OwSyqh -> `T` is `Dog&` in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When `T` is a template argument `T&&` is a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), not a r-value one. `T` gets deduced as `T` for r-values and `T&` for l-values. Such a reference binds to anything.

Comment: Would there be a way to constrain the template function signature so that it only accepts rvalue references (outside of a `static_assert`)?

Comment: @MaxLanghof SFINAE (with alias templates is nice).

Comment: You can do `enable_if<!is_reference<T>::value>` on the return value to reject l-values.

Comment: Oh right, that would of course work.

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you sure `not a X one` is right, rather than `not X one`? Because article _a_ is derived from _one_ and you don't say _a one man_.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin It reads better to me using `not a X one`.  Could probably change it to *not an r-value reference* to make it even better

Comment: @NathanOliver Technically it should be "a**n** r-value", because you pronounce it "arr-value".

Comment: Is it just me who thinks it's daft for one type of reference to mutate into another just because I wanted to walk other types of animal?

Answer (score 5):

```
template<class T> 
void walk(T && d)
```

in this case *T&&* is forwarding reference, when you pass Lvalue (`mydog` object) `T` is deduced to be `T&`, so signature of `walk` looks like

```
void walk(Dog& );
```

then you can bind `mydog` to Lvalue reference.

Comment: Do note the term is now forwarding reference instead of universal reference.  It's name comes from the fact the you're typically `forward`ing those parameters along.

Comment: @NathanOliver The much good scott did in pointing out a name is needed, the much confusion is now added because there are two different names...